# in_array() doesn't work as expected with associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what's causing this issue, but I'll post the code below then go through what I've done so far and the results I've gotten.

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com' => null, // first array entry
    'email@ex-two.com'   => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_three',
    'email@ex-four.com' => null,
);

$form_email = 'email@ex-two.com';


if (!empty($form_email)) {
    if (isset($client_emails[$form_email])) {
         $client_page = $client_emails[$form_email];
    } else { $client_page = null; }
}

if (in_array($form_email, $client_emails)) {
 if (!is_null($client_page)) {
     echo 'All seems to be good! - ';
     echo $client_page;
 } else {
     echo 'You can not be here.';
 }
} else {
     echo "For some reason this isn't working... 'in_array' should be finding the email in the array.";
}
```

The above code is what I've been playing with, it does not work. It will work, however, if we change the value for the `'first array entry' (comment)` from `NULL` to `TRUE`, like so:

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com' => true, // first array entry
    'email@ex-two.com'   => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_three',
    'email@ex-four.com' => null,
);
```

The whole thing technically works now, but `TRUE` is equal to `1` and now the rest of my script does not work properly because it will read that as a value of `1` and echo it. I need it to be `NULL`.

The `'first array entry'` cannot be `NULL` or `FALSE`, the only value that works is `TRUE`. It can be empty IF the value for `$form_email` is equal to a key that does not have a value, if the key has a value and there is no value of `TRUE` for the first array key then the whole thing fails any ways.

[<kbd>**Code to reproduce the issue**</kbd>](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d5a145fded531320742cd25803a2ab6079608cf)

I don't understand what's happening. I have two questions:

1. Any suggestions on how to get around this?
2. If you could help me understand why this is happening -- maybe I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried the following:

```
$client_emails = array(
    'email@ex-one.com' => 'null', // first array entry
    'email@ex-two.com'   => 'page_two',
    'email@ex-three.com' => 'page_three',
    'email@ex-four.com' => 'null',
);

$form_email = 'email@ex-two.com';


if (!empty($form_email)) {
    if (isset($client_emails[$form_email])) {
         $client_page = $client_emails[$form_email];
    } else { $client_page = null; }
}

if (in_array($form_email, $client_emails)) {
 if (!empty($client_page) && $client_page != 'null') {
     echo 'All seems to be good! - ';
     echo $client_page;
 } else {
     echo 'You can not be here.';
 }
} else {
     echo "For some reason this isn't working... 'in_array' should be finding the email in the array.";
}
```

Comment: Use !empty() method to check the 0,null values.

Comment: Array key exists instead of in array should do the trick . I'm array checks for values but you're using keys.

Comment: `isset` checks whether the given variable exists **and is not `null`**.

Comment: Okay, so !empty() vs isset, what is both of your opinions on this?

Comment: @deceze But since he then checks, if the e-mail is there, it works, because if it is there and isset() returns FALSE, the value is NULL.

Comment: See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's `isset` And `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @deceze just finished reading that article, it helped me understand a lot more about those two functions, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your if statement:

```
if (in_array($form_email, $client_emails))
```

Here you search the email in the values (`[NULL, "page_two", "page_three", NULL]`), but you need to look into the keys (`["email@ex-one.com", ..., "email@ex-four.com"]`), so just use `array_keys()`, e.g.

```
if (in_array($form_email, array_keys($client_emails)))
                        //^^^^^^^^^^^ See here, so you serach the email in the keys
```

Comment: I appreciate all of the detail you've included, I know this may seem like a simple thing on your end but I'm still new to PHP, only been doing this for a few months, I've been trying to figure this out all day lol, just waiting to accept the answer!

Comment: @Matthew You're welcome. (Since your new to PHP it's even more important, that you can see, where you went wrong and understand, what's going on.)

Comment: `in_array(array_keys)` is pretty darn inefficient. You just want `array_key_exists`!

Comment: @deceze Yes it is also an option, but I wanted to leave the `in_array()` from OP's code and show that he searches in the values. So for the logic `in_` **array** I choose to use **array** `_keys()` to show what he did wrong. (I should have included `array_key_exists()` as better solution, after the explanation, what he did wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
if(array_key_exists($form_email, $client_emails)){

}
```

Comment: That does make more sense!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `$form_email` with the values of `$client_emails`.

```
if (in_array($form_email, $client_emails)) {
```

`$form_email` should be compared with the keys of `$client_emails`, not values. - Try with -

```
if (in_array($form_email, array_keys($client_emails))) {
```

Or check for the existence of they -

```
if(array_key_exists($form_email, $client_emails)) {
```